# The Fourier Series of $f(x)= \int_{0}^{x} \log\sqrt{|\sin(\frac{t}{2})|} dt , -\pi < x < \pi $

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

This was a question on my exam in Fourier Analysis and I couldn't do it.
I had to find the Fourier Series of
$$f(x)= \int_{0}^{x} \log\sqrt{\left|\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right|} dt , -\pi < x < \pi $$

How?

Comment: I know that f is odd so there won't be a cosine/independent term, just sines.

Comment: I tried Fourier coefficients didn't take me anywhere.

Comment: Wait, or is it even?

Comment: The integrand is even, so $f$ is odd.

Comment: Note that $2\lvert \sin \frac{t}{2}\rvert = \lvert 1 - e^{it}\rvert$. Find the Fourier series of $f'$ first.

Comment: that gives me $\sqrt{2-2cos(t)}$ is that right?

Comment: **Hint:**  the fourier series of $f(x)=-\log(2\sin(\frac{x}{2} )$ for $0<x<π$ is :$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} \frac{\cos(nx)}{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:
The fourier series of $$-\log\bigg(2\sin\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)\bigg)$$ for $0<x<π,$ is :$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} \frac{\cos(nx)}{n}$$
$$\text{Hence : }\frac{1}{2}\log\bigg(\sin\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)\bigg)=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}\bigg)-\frac{\log(2)}{2}  \qquad (1) $$
$$\text{Let } f(x)=\int_0^x \log\sqrt{|\sin(t/2)|}dt$$
$$f'(x)=\log\sqrt{|\sin(\frac{x}{2})|}$$
$$=(1)$$
$$\sum_n\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}\text{ does converge uniformly in }(0,\pi)$$
$$\text{So, }f(x)=\int_0^xf'(t)dt=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg(\int_0^x\frac{\cos(nt)}{n}dt\bigg)-\int_0^x\frac{\log(2)}{2}dt$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}\bigg)-x\frac{\log(2)}{2}.$$

Comment: I took a long time to comment because I really needed time to digest this. I didn't know the fourier series of log(sin) etc...

Comment: I have a doubt, how about the interval $]-\pi,0[$ ?

Comment: Is it just the Additive inverse?